# Центрировать карту на первом результате поиска из searchControl без попапа и метки на карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Возник вопрос по поводу поведения searchControl.

Суть в том, что если я меняю свойство provider на yandex#map, перестаёт работать смена центра карты по результату запроса.

Если я его совсем не задаю или задаю yandex#search, то всё работает. Но поиск по организациям мне не нужен, нужен только по городам/улицам.
В документации сказано, что по умолчанию провайдер yandex#map, хотя судя по всему стоит yandex#search.

Подскажите пожалуйста, yandex#map так и должен себя вести?
Можно как-то оставить функционал центровки карты по первому результату?

Вот код подключения searchControl:

```js
map.controls.add('searchControl', {
    noPopup: true,
    noPlacemark: true,
    noCentering: false,
    provider: "yandex#map"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Провайдер поиска `yandex#map`, действительно, провайдер по умолчанию. Указывать его дополнительно не нужно.

Как работает поиск с точки зрения контрола:

- Если найден единственный результат, то карта центрируется на нем и ставится метка.
- Если найдено несколько результатов, то появляется попап со списком, из которого пользовать выбирает нужный результат. После этого также центрируется карта и ставится метка.

Что вы делаете в своём коде:

`noPopup: true` - отключает попап со списком найденных результатов;

`noPlacemark: true` - отключает отображение метки результата поиска;

`noCentering: false` - карта должна центрироваться на результате поиска, опцию указывать не нужно, потому что она и так [по дефолту `false`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/?from=SO#param-parameters.options.noCentering).

`provider: "yandex#map"` - искать только топонимы, опцию указывать не нужно, потому что она и так [по дефолту имеет это значение](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/?from=SO#param-parameters.options.provider).

Итого, код должен быть таким:

```
map.controls.add('searchControl', {
    noPopup: true,
    noPlacemark: true
});
```

Поскольку вы отключаете попап с результатами поиска, то карта не центрируется, если нашлось более одного результата - ожидается, что пользователь сначала выберет в попапе, а на чем собственно центрироваться.

Варианта у вас два:

1. Не скрывать попап результатов поиска.
2. Самостоятельно выбирать первый результат и центрировать на нём карту. [Вот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search_results?from=SO).